# How to create a new data set depending on the values at certain array indexes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array that contains multiple objects and each object has an array called data that contains multiple data.

```
"datasets": [
  {
    data: [1227.0, 698.4, 2903.1, 7280.2, 5447.9]
  },
  {
    data: [302.0, 170.7, 592.2, 1293.6, 961.3]
  },
  {
    data: [239.0, 275.5, 353.5, 478.0, 576.9]
  }, 
  ...
]
```

For each data array that I have, how can I write a logic so that I store the values for each matching index into a new array data set. For example, I need to generate a new array which would only contains the values at index zero like so:

```
[1227.0, 302.0, 239.0]
```

and then another array which would contain the values at index one only

```
[698.4, 170.7, 275.5]
```

The desired output that I need is the following:

```
"result": [
  {
    data: [1227.0, 302.0, 239.0]
  },
  {
    data: [698.4, 170.7, 275.5]
  },
  {
    data: [2903.1, 592.2, 353.5]
  }, 
  {
    data: [7280.2, 1293.6, 478.0]
  },
  {
    data: [5447.9, 961.3, 576.9]
  }
]
```

How will I achieve this. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you need to transpose your data. Here's one possible solution:

Assuming this was nested inside an object called dataset:

Ex:

```
const dataSet = {
"datasets": [
  {
    data: [1227.0, 698.4, 2903.1, 7280.2, 5447.9]
  },
  {
    data: [302.0, 170.7, 592.2, 1293.6, 961.3]
  },
  {
    data: [239.0, 275.5, 353.5, 478.0, 576.9]
  }, 
  ...
]
}
```

Now, this is a bit of a cumbersome process, but the solution would involve:

1. Iterating through every element object of dataSet["datasets"]
2. Create a new array upon every increment of i
3. Stopping at the jth element of dataSet["datasets"][i].data[j] and store that it in the array instance
4. When you've went through every object element's jth position, push that array instance into an output array.

Here's how one solution would look (O(n^2)) :

```
const matrixObjTranspose = (matrixObj) => {
  const output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < matrixObj.datasets[0].data.length; i += 1) {
    const newSubArr = [];
    for (let j = 0; j <  matrixObj.datasets.length; j += 1) {
      newSubArr.push(matrixObj.datasets[j].data[i]);
    }
    output.push(newSubArr);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(matrixObjTranspose(dataSet))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```js
const c = [
  {
    data: [1227.0, 698.4, 2903.1, 7280.2, 5447.9]
  },
  {
    data: [302.0, 170.7, 592.2, 1293.6, 961.3]
  },
  {
    data: [239.0, 275.5, 353.5, 478.0, 576.9]
  }]
  
  const convert = (arr) => {
  return arr.slice(1).reduce((sum, cur) => {
        return sum.map((v, i) => (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).concat(cur.data[i]))
    }, arr[0].data).map(v => ({data: v}))
  }
  
  console.log(convert(c))
```